# Multithreaded slower than singlethreaded

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a program which performs a matrix multiplication. I have multithreaded and singlethreaded versions. The multithreaded version is slower than singlethreaded and I don't know why. Could you explain me that?

Multithreaded (for size = 128, stopwatch shows around **5** seconds):

```
private static SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(size, size);
(...)
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    threads[i] = new Thread(() => Multiply(ref a, ref b, ref c));
    threads[i].Name = i.ToString();
    threads[i].Start();
}
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    threads[i].Join();
(...)
public static void Multiply(ref float[,] a, ref float[,] b, ref float[,] c)
{
    int index = int.Parse(Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
    semaphore.Wait();
    for (int j = 0; j < c.GetLength(0); j++)
        for (int k = 0; k < c.GetLength(0); k++)
            c[index, j] += a[index, k] * b[k, j];
    semaphore.Release();
}
```

Singlethreaded (for size = 128, stopwatch shows around **3** seconds):

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    Multiply(i, ref a, ref b, ref c);
(...)   
public static void Multiply(int i, ref float[,] a, ref float[,] b, ref float[,] c)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < c.GetLength(0); j++)
        for (int k = 0; k < c.GetLength(0); k++)
            c[i, j] += a[i, k] * b[k, j];
}
```

Comment: Can it be the additional time for join threads? Actually, it can take some significant amount.

Comment: There is no concurrency at all because of the semaphore.  So it will never be faster.  And worse, it will never be faster than the slowest thread.   It gets substantially slower when you have a worker thread do so little work, now the overhead from creating the thread and context-switching starts to add up.  Never invent your own matrix multiplier, that's been done and thoroughly optimized.

Comment: Also you don't get unlimited speedup. If you have 16 cores then you should probably only be using around 16 threads, "For size = 128" you appear to be creating 128 threads, but a single processor doesn't run 8 threads faster than it does 1 thread and it can be slower.

Comment: yes, my take is that there is overhead in creating new threads and then joining. What I don't understand is why you're using a semaphore, can you explain your logic?

Comment: @corrego I have to use semaphore to synchronize threads.

Comment: @HansPassant I have to use semaphore. How to make concurrency with it?

Comment: You can't both use the semaphore and have concurrency. The entire point of the semaphore is to prevent concurrency. If you can't make a parallel implementation that doesn't need exclusive access to a resource, don't make a parallel implementation at all. Only certain types of problems are candidates for parallel execution.

Comment: Ok, the last question, I want to be sure - threads are running parallel or not? Or I have to fix something in code?

Comment: Threads MIGHT run in parallel. On the other hand they might not. If there is a bottleneck on shared resources - CPU cores, or shared resources like locks, semaphores, and mutexes - you might run entirely in serial. Your code above will run entirely in a serial fashion because of the semaphore.

Comment: In your current implementation I think you could remove the semaphore completely as 2 threads will never write to the same matrix element because you are passing in `index`. A common way to do matrix multiplication is to split the problem up into independent operations that each thread works on, then each thread sends their partial result back to a main thread which at the end combines all the partial results into a full answer. But you don't have to "combine" anything as each thread is currently calculating the final answer for the particular matrix element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not uncommon. Threads, and particularly thread synchronization, tend to add a lot of overhead. That's why multithreading is something you carefully consider, and why asynchronous but not multithreaded approaches are often the right answer.

If you are doing CPU heavy tasks, it is often better to do them on one or a small number of worker threads so they're not just pre-empting each other nonstop. Typically there is no performance gain - and in fact a performance hit - once the number of CPU-limited threads exceeds the available cores of the processor.

Imagine trying to get a class full of kindergarteners through a door to go to recess. It's actually faster to line them up and get them through in an orderly fashion than letting them all push each other out of the way and fight to get through first.

Even before the point where your threads fight for CPU time, threading can still slow you down if it takes more time on thread & synchronization overhead than you gain by parallelizing the tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Multi-threading is not always faster than single-threading. The additional overhear of creating threads and synchronization may contribute significantly to the time it takes to complete your problem. Also there are other factors that may work against multi threading like how many cores does your CPU have (the lower the worst for multi-threading performance).